# Workflow module blocked my admin user

Tags: 7, workflows

today i was adding the workflow module to my site and as i was not clear i used a trigger in it. using this trigger I blocked the current user to view the page and now if i login from my admin user it just tell me that *The username webmaster has not been activated or is blocked.*
please guide me what to do to restore my old position.

Comment: Take a look at [drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush). In the meantime, if you think it's a bug in workflow, you should report it on drupal.org, and if you don't, consider editing title as it's something you did, not the innocent module ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use below Drush command to reset admin password.

```
> drush uli
    (or)
> drush uli user_name

// Display a one time login link for the given user account (defaults to uid 1).
```

Just copy the one time login link and paste it your browser. Here you will get reset password option.

After successfully login, disbale the workflow module and go ahead.

More about [Drush](http://drush.ws/).